# See live which files from my list are growing the fastest

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of ~70 files (logs) in different directories that are continuously growing.

I'd like a way to see which ones are growing the fastest. Ideally see the 10 fastest growing since I ran the command to monitor them, shown in real time.

Comment: You might want to edit the post to include what kind of technologies you have in mind in the title / body of the question, rather than just tags :)

Comment: What's your question? You'll have to write some code, obviously. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the top 10 largest files among your list:

```
watch bash -c "ls -S FILES | head"
```

If you want the rate of growth to be tracked them you'll need to do that yourself as there is no built-in command for that.